# how to best assign the pointer onto a _vector_ object to a "void *" variable in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012, vector

I have the scenario where I have two "worlds" of C++ codes separated by a calling barrier that is only C for design reasons. (in more detail: I have a main thread and multiple child threads where each of the childs can service me calling a bunch of functions with a passed set of arguments and returning the functions result. the interconnect is pure C but the architecture is shared memory and the data to pass are for some of the calls C++ vector objects.)

Doing it the simple way on a vector failed for me - this statement only gets the pointer on the data of the object but not the object pointer itself:

```
vector<something> my_object;
void * argv0 = &my_object;
```

If I learnt the right way the class is designed for providing me a pointer onto it's data array rather than a pointer on the object (which further has special members for management like size or allocated space). as the target layer is not capable to manage and update the special members it will happen that any need for alterations to that area can not be done. In other words the "operator=" has a class-defined pairing of "(void *) = (vector)" and I don't see how to overcome that in a direct C++ fashion.

My next best guess was this C fashion approach:

```
typedef union
{
    void *              pvObject;
    vector<something> * pcObject;
} VECTOR_VOID_UNION_T;

vector<something> my_object;
VECTOR_VOID_UNION_T uVV;
uVV.pcObject = &my_object;
void * argv0 = uVV.pvObject;
```

I am really not sure if this is the best or only way to do it in a case with such sort of class design. There might be other operators like the C++ extended casting operators that might solve the access problem to the object pointer itself much more gently. but as of now any attempt I tried out did not give me success.

My question is now:
How to correctly and more elegantly overcome that class-defined =operator (or one of it's equivalents) in a C++ fashion so that finally the pointer to the vector object [edit: not the vector data] is stored in the variable of type "void*"?

Comment: is my_object.data() what you are looking for?

Comment: nope. it's the vector object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
void *argv0 = reinterpret_cast<void *>(&my_object);
```

Comment: after testing it in my codes it looks like this hits exactly the point.
this works for the forward and for the backward conversion operation. here is just for anyone's reference the _abstract_ code for the backwards conversion at the receiving thread (derived from my implementation. i am only assuming it compiles and works):

'vector<something> * pMyObject = reinterpret_cast< vector<something> * >( argv0 );'

Comment: i think (=maybe) my main problem was that in the decoding i got a "void*" assigned to an object pointer but due to the =operator overloading & thus triggered in this line some new and thus independent vector object was silently created on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a `void*` that points to the vector's data:

```
assert(!theVector.empty());
void* thePtr = static_cast<void*>(theVector.data());
```

It's kind of hard to tell what you're asking, though.

Comment: i dont want a pointer to the data array, i want a pointer to the vector object itself.

Comment: @alex: Why? You're not going to be able to use it from the C end.. But if so just `(void*)&myVector`....

Comment: because of an overloaded =operator !?!

Comment: @alex: I have no idea what you're saying. C doesn't have overloaded operators. Can you try to be more clear as to your goals?

Comment: also the vice versa of assigning the "void *" to a pointer on a vector object might have had the =operator overloading problem. (maybe because such assignment was creating a **duplicate** object on the fly!) i dealt with both places at the same time so i am not determined.

Comment: @alex: Nope, still not getting it. Where does casting to `void*` come into it to avoid making copies? That is not how you deal with object lifetimes.

Comment: vector object != vector data

Comment: @alex: The object is responsible for managing the data. That is literally its purpose. So what is the distinction in your mind?

Comment: The term "object" covers the data array **and** the special members for management like size or allocated space and sometimes even silently hidden the jump tables for e.g. overloaded functionality.